# Logarithmic equation question: finding all integer solutions.

Tags: logarithms, contest-math

Find all positive integers (x,y) such that

$2^x +\log_3x=y^2$

and

$2^y +\log_3y=x^2$

Hi guys so i managed to find a solution for the system ie (3,3) however i cant seem to find anymore. I think its the only solution to the system but i cant be sure so id like a proof for thst.

Answer (score 0):

If $x, y \ge 4$, you'd need $y > 2^{x/2} \ge x$, but similarly $x > 2^{y/2} \ge y$.

Comment: how does that work ?